# Nonlinear form of ANCOVA?

Tags: anova, nonlinear-regression, ancova, case-control-study

I would like to compare a control group against a test group using something like ANCOVA. However, the covariates are not simple, as some items may have already been increasing with time, others decreasing, all in a non-linear fashion. How would I do a similar analysis with a nonlinear model?

I found a relevant answer here ([Repeated measure t test with covariates in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84164/repeated-measure-t-test-with-covariates-in-)) but it doesn't include cases where the covariates have a nonlinear relationship. I'd like to think I could just do a nonlinear predictive model and then do ANOVA on the residuals. I feel like as long as it follows the assumptions of ANOVA are satisfied I should be okay ([ANOVA assumption normality/normal distribution of residuals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/anova-assumption-normality-normal-distribution-of-residuals)). Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by non-linear?  Do you mean in the sense that you can't solve with least squares?  Or in the sense that your covariates don't steadily increase/decrease in a linear, straight-line fashion?

Comment: My primary covariate is time. The test and control groups vary in a nonlinear fashion with time. If the test had not happened, I should be able to predict the value fairly well, but with some error. I could just predict the next days' results and compare the residuals against that prediction. My question is whether that is statistically rigorous, as long as the residuals follow those assumptions.