# Control covariates in paired t-tests (pretest-posttest design)

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, linear-model, paired-data, ancova

Suppose we have a naïve single-arm pretest-posttest design without any control group. Every `subject` has a `pretest` score and a `posttest` score. If we want to determine whether there is a significant difference between the means of `pretest` and `posttest` and how large the difference (or effect size) is, we can carry out a paired t-test. However, there are other confounding variables, such as `gender` and `age`. How can we control them?

I come up with three models:

1. Transform `pretest` and `posttest` into a factor `test` (with `pre` and `post` as its possible values) and a continuous variable `score` (transform the wide data into long data). Then build the mixed-effects model `score ~ test + gender + age + (1 | subject)`. If we omit the `gender` and `age` terms, the result (slope of `test`) will exactly be the same as the result of a paired t-test (see [Paired data comparison: regression or paired t-test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352285/paired-data-comparison-regression-or-paired-t-test/352478#352478)).
2. Treat `posttest` as the response variable and `pretest` as a covariate. Build the model `posttest ~ pretest + gender + age` (see [Repeated measure t test with covariates in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84164/repeated-measure-t-test-with-covariates-in-r/84181#84181)). If we have both a treatment group and a control group, and we want to measure the `treatment` effect, this (`posttest ~ treatment + pretest + gender + age`) will be the preferred way to build models (see [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs)). However, what if we have no control group and just want to measure the pretest-posttest difference? And if we indeed use this model, what will be the effect size? (I assume the intercept can be used to calculate the  the effect size when the slope of `pretest` is 1; what if it isn't 1?).
3. Build the model `(posttest − pretest) ~ 1 + I(pretest − mean(pretest)) + gender + age` according to [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4297322). The intercept can be used to calculate the effect size.

Which model is the most suitable one? And why? Thanks!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen My second model is built according to this link. However, my study is single-arm and there is no control group, so I reckon that the advice from the link is not directly relevant.

Comment: Here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84164/repeated-measure-t-test-with-covariates-in-r there's a mention that because you do within-subject comparison there shouldn't be any need to adjust for covariates. However, I am wondering in case of clustering (i.e. subejcts are recruited in different centres), your first proposition would be preferable for being able to adjust for this in the random effects with some nesting of subejcts and centres.